# Too many capture groups htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
&property_type=$1&sell_type=$3&area1=$7&area2=$9&price=$11&page=$12
```

I'm having an issue with capture groups in a RewriteRule. $11 becomes $1's value and 1. So let's say $1 is "house", $11 ends up being "house1". Is there a way to force htaccess to get the 11th capture group rather than the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need all 12 capture groups?

If not you can deploy *non-capturing groups* (specifically intended to help you conserve backreferences).

Where the syntax for a capture group is:

```
(REGEX_HERE)
```

the syntax for a non-capturing group is:

```
(?:REGEX_HERE)
```